# jQuery onclick submenu open and still no go

Tags: jquery, navbar

I am trying to learn jQuery and did some research online and I am making mistakes. This is really sad and I need your help with this.

[Here is my code in codepen website](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BmpaVa), please see my code and change it if possible and save it. I have that code in my local machine.

```
$('a.footer-site-link-sub-menu:firstchild').css({cursor: "pointer"}).on('click', function(){
  $(ul.footer-sub-links).find('ul li').classList.toggle("show");
});
```

Comment: Hi @Naveen. It appears to me that you are new to the site. I understand that you have run into an issue and need help. However, to get better answers, you should phrase your question better. Give details about what you are trying to achieve. GIve instances of things that you tried already but did not help. Mention if you are getting any errors. Give this a read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Will look forward to an edited version of this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code as your script may this help you.

```
 $(function(){
        $('a.footer-site-link-sub-menu').on('click',  function(e){

            if($(this).next("ul").hasClass("footer-sub-links"))
            {
                 $(this).next("ul.footer-sub-links").removeClass("footer-sub-links").addClass("show");        
            }
          else
            {
              $(this).next("ul.show").removeClass("show").addClass("footer-sub-links");
            }

             e.preventDefault();

        }).css({cursor: "pointer"});
    });
```

[codepen link](https://codepen.io/addyis1/pen/zPNxEy?editors=0110)